# How to skip validation(acts as taggable on gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm trying to figure out how to add tags to users table and skip validation(password, etc.) or something else.

---

*user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  authenticates_with_sorcery!

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates :password, length: { in: 6..20 }

  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
end
```

---

*settings_controller.rb*

```
  class SettingsController < ApplicationController
    def add_tag
      current_user.tag_list.add(params[:name])
      current_user.save!
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end
```

---

Then I get error validation `Validation failed: Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)`. How do fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove:

```
validates :password, length: { in: 6..20 }
```

from the model.

You have these two validation for your password:

```
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates :password, length: { in: 6..20 }
```

The first one: `validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create` will make sure the password is present when you `create` an user. If the password is not present, it will not allow to create the user.
The second validation: `validates :password, length: { in: 6..20 }` will make sure the length of the password must have to be between 6 and 20.

So, if you want to add tags to an existing user i.e. update the user, then you just can remove this validation: `validates :password, length: { in: 6..20 }` or do this validation on `create` only like this:

```
  validates :password, length: { in: 6..20 }, :on => :create
```

That way, it will not fail when you update an user and the validaiton will be applicable for `create` action only and will allow you to update the record without failing.

Comment: `validates :password, length: { in: 6..20 }, :on => :create` very helpful

Comment: Glad I could help :-)